# Examplebox from Beamer in Article

Tags: article

I would like use **`\examplebox{}{}` command** from Beamer **in** document class **Article**.

[image: ExampleBox]

Is it possible? Or can I define it somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed) for beamer-like boxes and for quite a lot more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\mdfdefinestyle{beamerlikebox}{
leftmargin=1cm,
rightmargin=1cm,
shadow=true,
roundcorner=5pt,
backgroundcolor=gray!30,
linecolor=gray!30,
shadowcolor=gray,
shadowsize=6pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=beamerlikebox]
``Two beers or not two beers, details...''

{\hfill --- Shakes beer}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]